# Date picker shows behind modal dialog after rendering rhandsontable

Tags: jquery, r, shiny, modal-dialog, handsontable

I'm using handsontables and modal dialogs in a Shiny app and the two don't seem to like each other. More specifically, once a handsontable has been produced through `rhandsontableOutput`, inputs inside the modal dialog that use jQuery behave oddly. For a reproducible example see below. You'll notice that before calling the handsontable everything works fine, but once the checkbox has been ticked the datepicker shows up behind the modal dialog (a similar issue was raised [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1408) before, but not in the context of handsontables). Note that I'm intentionally using this slightly odd way rendering the handsontable through `renderUI` to make sure that the modal works fine as long as the checkbox is not ticked.

I'm using version 1.4.0.2 of shiny and 0.3.7 of rhandsontable.

Grateful for any advice!

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  helpText("Click this first. Date picker should work fine."),
  actionButton("show", "Show modal"),
  hr(),
  helpText("Now click below to render the handsontable. When showing the modal again, the date picker shows up behind the modal."),
  checkboxInput("showHot", "Show handsontable"),
  uiOutput("hot_rendered")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Modal:
  observeEvent(input$show, {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        title = "My Modal",
        dateInput("date", "Choose date")
      )
    )
  })
  # Handsontable:
  output$hot_rendered = renderUI({
    req(input$showHot==T)
    rHandsontableOutput("hot")
  })
  output$hot = renderRHandsontable({
    req(input$showHot==T)
    rhandsontable(head(iris))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its a known issue https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/914, you can adjust the `z-index` yourself:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$style(HTML(".datepicker {z-index:99999 !important;}")),

    helpText("Click this first. Date picker should work fine."),
    actionButton("show", "Show modal"),
    hr(),
    helpText("Now click below to render the handsontable. When showing the modal again, the date picker shows up behind the modal."),
    checkboxInput("showHot", "Show handsontable"),
    uiOutput("hot_rendered")
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # Modal:
    observeEvent(input$show, {
        showModal(
            modalDialog(
                title = "My Modal",
                dateInput("date", "Choose date")
            )
        )
    })
    # Handsontable:
    output$hot_rendered = renderUI({
        req(input$showHot==T)
        rHandsontableOutput("hot")
    })
    output$hot = renderRHandsontable({
        req(input$showHot==T)
        rhandsontable(head(iris))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]